Unresolved reference AndroidSchedulers
I'm using version 2.1.1 of RxAndroid and 2.0.1 of RxJava, but I have no access to AndroidSchedulers.
I made sure my dependencies are properly declared in the app gradle build, and I tried the following import: import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers, but the symbol still isn't recognized.
